# Is there any company that is still using Pro*C SQL?

Tags: c++, oracle-pro-c

There is a semester where each student need to develop a system using VB.NET. As time goes by, its become easy to just copy and paste others project and edit the interface, images, etc. So my lecturers decided to change from using VB.NET, now we all have to use Pro*C SQL to connect to the Oracle using C++.
I personally support and help the lecturers to provide the guide necessary to start on using Pro*C since I have done it before. The reason is that without proper knowledge of basic programming, students will not be able to just copy, paste and edit any Pro*C project.
My question is that, how practical is this kind of approach? And does any other company that are still using Pro*C SQL out there? Google does not bring me much recent result. I hope this is the best place to ask this kind of question

Comment: Why don't you use OCCI for your students project? The code will be way easier to understand and to write, and you get rid of that ugly Pro*C preprocessor that is producing cryptic code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I have been part of many companies which use pro*c for many batch program development. Retail-billing,car-rental and telecom billing are some of the domains that I have worked with that still use pro*c. This methodology is quite successful and I have seen many applications that have been running for last 15 years or so. Hope I answered your question.